# How to use Cauchy-Reimann equations to show that complex conjugate of a variable be treated as a constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Why can the complex conjugate of a variable be treated as a constant when differentiating with respect to that variable?

Comment: maybe this question can help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852978/meaning-of-fz-barz

Comment: What I'm really asking is if z = x+j*y and zbar = x-j*y. When z is differentiated with respect to any variable and nonzero, either x must change or y must change. But if either x or y changes, then zbar must also change, making it not possible to differentiate z with respect to given variable while keeping zbar constant with respect to that same variable.

Answer (score 1):

The Wirtinger derivative $\frac{\partial }{\partial z}$ is a *derivation*, meaning that it is linear in $f$ and satisfies the Leibniz rule 
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial z}(fg)=f\frac{\partial }{\partial z}g
+ g \frac{\partial }{\partial z}f
$$
(Easy to derive from the standard Leibniz rule.) In addition, a direct calculation shows that 
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial z}\bar z=0
$$
Combined, the above facts imply that
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial z}(\bar z f)=\bar z\frac{\partial }{\partial z}( f)
$$
for any real-differentiable function $f$. Repeated implication of the above shows that 
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial z}(\bar z^n f)=\bar z^n\frac{\partial }{\partial z}( f)
$$
for every integer $n$. Finally, real-analytic functions can be differentiated by taking the derivative of their power series term-by-term, which justifies computations like
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial z}(e^{\bar z} f)=e^{\bar z}\frac{\partial }{\partial z}( f)
$$